# How can I read diffgram file generated by XmlDiff.Compare()

Tags: c#, testcomplete, xmldiff

I am comparing two XML files using XMLDiff.compare() Which I am using for the first time and unable to figure out what to do with the diffgram file generated to generate an HTML for the Difference in the two XMLs.

```
bool bIdentical = xmldiff.Compare(originalFile, newFile, false, diffgramWriter);
```

where original file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsOutputData>
<TestName_AK1>
    <FeatureID ID="33B50792-207E514">
        <Intance_ID_1 >
            <CommandString>ABC </CommandString>
            <ProductID>100000</ProductID>
            <ProjectName>No Project</ProjectName>
            <TaskID>TESTSUITE</TaskID>
            <Type>Local</Type>
            <User></User>
        </Intance_ID_1>
        <Intance_ID_2>
            <CommandString>PQR </CommandString>
            <ProductID>1000</ProductID>
            <ProjectName>No Project</ProjectName>
            <TaskID>TESTSUITE</TaskID>
            <Type>Local</Type>
            <User></User>
        </Intance_ID_2>
        <Intance_ID_3>
            <CommandString>ABC </CommandString>
            <ProductID>1000</ProductID>
            <ProjectName>No Project</ProjectName>
            <TaskID>TESTSUITE</TaskID>
            <Type>Local</Type>
            <User></User>
        </Intance_ID_3>
    </FeatureID>
</TestName_AK1>
```

And new file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsOutputData>
<TestName_AK1>
    <FeatureID ID="33B50792-207E514">
        <Intance_ID_2>
            <CommandString>PQR </CommandString>
            <ProductID>1000</ProductID>
            <ProjectName>No Project</ProjectName>
            <TaskID>TESTSUITE</TaskID>
            <Type>Local</Type>
            <User></User>
        </Intance_ID_2>
        <Intance_ID_1 >
            <CommandString>ABC </CommandString>
            <ProductID>100000</ProductID>
            <ProjectName>No Project</ProjectName>
            <TaskID>TESTSUITE</TaskID>
            <Type>Local</Type>
            <User></User>
        </Intance_ID_1>
        <Intance_ID_3>
            <CommandString>ABC </CommandString>
            <ProductID>1000</ProductID>
            <ProjectName>No Project</ProjectName>
            <TaskID>TESTSUITE</TaskID>
            <Type>Local</Type>
            <User></User>
        </Intance_ID_3>
    </FeatureID>
</TestName_AK1>
```

the diffgramwriter generated is

```
<xd:xmldiff version="1.0" srcDocHash="11314582626391529293" options="None" fragments="no" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xmltools/2002/xmldiff">
<xd:node match="2">
<xd:node match="1">
  <xd:node match="1">
    <xd:add match="/2/1/1/2" opid="1" />
    <xd:remove match="2" opid="1" />
  </xd:node>
</xd:node>
</xd:node>
<xd:descriptor opid="1" type="move" />
</xd:xmldiff>
```

now using this need to generate HTML file.(This is later part)
But I am not able to understand(read) the diffgram file properly,
not able to get the meaning of

```
<xd:add match="/2/1/1/2" opid="1" />
    <xd:remove match="2" opid="1" />
```

and

```
<xd:descriptor opid="1" type="move" />
```

and their are more of this type node in other diffgram for other cases.
how can i understand this diffgram file in such a way that I can generate an an HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consume your diffgram in XmlDiffView class. But for me it doesn't work perfectly. It highlights the difference but also shows that I deleted some nodes and added new.

```
XmlDiffView dv = new XmlDiffView();
//Load the original file again and the diff file.
XmlTextReader orig = new XmlTextReader("F:\\XML_1.xml");
        XmlTextReader diffGram = new XmlTextReader("F:\\diff.xml");
        dv.Load(orig,
            diffGram);

        //Wrap the HTML file with necessary html and 
        //body tags and prepare it before passing it to the GetHtml method.

        string tempFile =  "F:\\diff" +r.Next() + ".htm";
        StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(tempFile);
        sw1.Write("<html><body><table width='100%'>");
        //Write Legend.
        sw1.Write("<tr><td colspan='2' align='center'><b>Legend:</b> <font style='background-color: yellow'" +
            " color='black'>added</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: red'" +
            " color='black'>removed</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: " +
            "lightgreen' color='black'>changed</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
            "<font style='background-color: red' color='blue'>moved from</font>" +
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: yellow' color='blue'>moved to" +
            "</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font style='background-color: white' color='#AAAAAA'>" +
            "ignored</font></td></tr>");

        dv.GetHtml(sw1);
        sw1.Write("</table></body></html>");
        sw1.Close();
        dv = null;
        orig.Close();
        diffGram.Close();
```

I ran this using your xml files and they are equal. When I modified the value CommandString from ABC to ABCD I got highligted changed value.