# VS/xUnit/FluentAssertions: Provide file link in test message

Tags: xml, visual-studio, diff, xunit.net, fluent-assertions

In some of my tests I have to compare the content of XML files with some reference files (*golden files* approach). For comparing the XML files, I'm using [XmlDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx), which produces HTML pointing out the differences of the files (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536373/how-can-i-read-diffgram-file-generated-by-xmldiff-compare)).

Now, in case a test fails, it would be nice to have a link to the diff file as part of the test's message, such that the user can click on it and verify the differences in a browser (preferably within VS). Is that possible at all? I have tried `See diff at C:\myabsolutepath\diff.html` as well as `See diff at file:C:\myabsolutepath\diff.html` in the hope that VS test explorer would pick up the links, but without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried wrong file path formats. This one will work:

```
"file:///c:/myabsolutepath/diff.html"
```

Comment: Works just fine, although it's a bit ugly... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This nice format for above

```
new Uri("c:/myabsolutepath/diff.html").AbsoluteUri
```